# In an operation between two objects in python whose overloading of the operation as priority?

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

For example if I have `__add__` and `__radd__` defined in two classes and I sum the two objects which definition of the operation will python use?

Comment: The left hand operand has priority.

Answer (score 4):

If the left and right hand objects are unrelated, then the left-hand object wins. However, if either object is a subclass of the other object, then the subclass wins regardless of whether it is the left or right hand object.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __add__(self, rhs):
...     print('foo.add')
...   def __radd__(self, rhs):
...     print('foo.radd')
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...   def __add__(self,rhs):
...     print('bar.add')
...   def __radd__(self, rhs):
...     print('bar.radd')
... 
>>> a=Foo()
>>> b=Bar()
>>> a+b
bar.radd
>>> b+a
bar.add
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

For an expression `lhs + rhs`, Python will first try `lhs.__add__(rhs)`, then `rhs.__radd__(lhs)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure neither, so I try it *on my own*:

```
In [84]: class Foo(object):
    ...:     def __add__(self, rhs):
    ...:         print 'foo.add'
    ...:         
    ...: class Bar(object):
    ...:     def __radd__(self, lhs):
    ...:         print 'bar.radd'
    ...: 
    ...: f=Foo(); b=Bar()
    ...: f+b
    ...: 1+b
foo.add
bar.radd
```

Then I remember the rule now.

Comment: That is only true if the objects are unrelated. If one of the objects is a subclass of the other, the subclass always wins.